# How to create a new column based on if any of a subset of columns are NA with the dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This feels like this should be possible with `mutate_at` or `mutate(across(...))`, but I'm not understanding something...

Suppose we have the following. I am including the desired output `desired` which is an indicator column based on whether any of the columns containing the word "test" have an `NA` value:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,    ~name, ~test_col, ~is_test, ~another_test, ~desired,
   1L, "mickey",        NA,      13L,           12L,       1L,
   2L, "donald",       19L,       NA,            NA,       1L,
   3L,  "daisy",       15L,      20L,           20L,       0L,
   4L,  "goofy",       18L,      14L,           10L,       0L,
   5L,  "pluto",       16L,      10L,            NA,       1L,
   6L, "minnie",       19L,      15L,           16L,       0L
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>      id name   test_col is_test another_test desired
#>   <int> <chr>     <int>   <int>        <int>   <int>
#> 1     1 mickey       NA      13           12       1
#> 2     2 donald       19      NA           NA       1
#> 3     3 daisy        15      20           20       0
#> 4     4 goofy        18      14           10       0
#> 5     5 pluto        16      10           NA       1
#> 6     6 minnie       19      15           16       0
```

But in reality we start without the `desired` column: `df_start <- df %>% select(-desired)`.

I can successfully use `fiter_at` to get only the observations where one or more of the columns containing "test" are `NA`:

```r
df_start %>% 
  filter_at(vars(contains("test")), any_vars(is.na(.)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id name   test_col is_test another_test
#>   <int> <chr>     <int>   <int>        <int>
#> 1     1 mickey       NA      13           12
#> 2     2 donald       19      NA           NA
#> 3     5 pluto        16      10           NA
```

I could save this subset and then do use bind_rows, but I would like to create the `desired` column in one pipeline. Again, this feels like this should be doable with `mutate_at` or `mutate(across(...))` but I have yet to be successful.

Question: How do you create the indicator column `desired` in one pipeline with dplyr?

<sup>Examples created on 2021-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: To all: I would like to give a second answer here. Because I just solved a big problem using across for me. And I think it is worth to share. Is this ok or should I update my first answer? I read this <https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice> But I am not sure. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(desired = +if_any(contains("test"), is.na))
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     id name   test_col is_test another_test desired
  <int> <chr>     <int>   <int>        <int>   <int>
1     1 mickey       NA      13           12       1
2     2 donald       19      NA           NA       1
3     3 daisy        15      20           20       0
4     4 goofy        18      14           10       0
5     5 pluto        16      10           NA       1
6     6 minnie       19      15           16       0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way how we could do it with `across`:

Update:
With the help of genius Martin Gal the short version:

```
df %>% 
    select(-desired) %>% 
    mutate(desired = +(rowSums(is.na(across(test_col:another_test))) > 0))
```

The long version, :-)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(-desired) %>% 
    mutate(across(test_col:another_test, ~ case_when(is.na(.) ~ 1, 
                                                     TRUE ~ 0), .names ="New_{.col}")) %>% 
    mutate(desired = ifelse(New_test_col == 1 | 
                            New_is_test == 1 |
                            New_another_test == 1, 1, 0), .keep="unused")
```

Output:

```
     id name   test_col is_test another_test desired
  <int> <chr>     <int>   <int>        <int>   <dbl>
1     1 mickey       NA      13           12       1
2     2 donald       19      NA           NA       1
3     3 daisy        15      20           20       0
4     4 goofy        18      14           10       0
5     5 pluto        16      10           NA       1
6     6 minnie       19      15           16       0
```

Comment: Uhrm... did you misstyped ` mutate(desired = +(rowSums(is.na(across(test_col:another_test))) > 0))`? ;-)

Comment: I am still on this case. Your answer is very good. `+` changes `TRUE` `FALSE` to `1` `0`. How you call this putting a `+` before `if_any`. Thanks for reply I will check the answer.

Comment: Thanks Martin I have updated my answer with your help!!!

Comment: `+is.na(rowSums(across(test_col:another_test)))` is better

Comment: across is just the selection helper here. The soul of this answer is `rowSums(condition)`

Comment: @TarJae Can we still leverage `contains` or other conditionals/regex in this type of call to `across`? While the columns are next to each other in the example, in "real life" we're not always as lucky.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns You could replace `test_col:another_test` with `contains("test")` inside of `across`. Other options include `matches()` (which uses regex matching),  `starts_with()` and  `ends_with()`.

Answer (score 3):

An option with `map/reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(desired = map(select(., contains('test')),is.na ) %>% 
          reduce(`|`) %>% 
       as.integer )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     id name   test_col is_test another_test desired
  <int> <chr>     <int>   <int>        <int>   <int>
1     1 mickey       NA      13           12       1
2     2 donald       19      NA           NA       1
3     3 daisy        15      20           20       0
4     4 goofy        18      14           10       0
5     5 pluto        16      10           NA       1
6     6 minnie       19      15           16       0
```

Comment: Always with the sorcery, but I like this! Teaches you to think differently about problems.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, every now and then the same answers always show up for these kinds of rowwise logical operations - MartinGals's `if_any()` , TarJae's `RowSums(across())` and akrun's `map%>%reduce`.

For completeness' sake, another common favourite, which is the most verbose and less elegant (and one of the least efficient ones), is the `pmap`approach:

```
output<-df%>%mutate(desired=pmap(across(contains('test')), ~{
        vector<-c(...)
        +any(is.na(vector))})

# OR simply

output<-df%>%mutate(desired=pmap(across(contains('test')), ~{
        +any(is.na(c(...)))})
```

Comment: But it's actually Martin ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, typo :-)